# Why didn't Lorentz conclude that no object can go faster than light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, faster-than-light, history

Based on Lorentz factor $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt {1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ it is easy to see $v < c$ since otherwise $\gamma$ would be either undefined or a complex number, which is non-physical. Also, as far as I understand this equation was known before Einstein's postulates were published. My question is: why didn't Lorentz himself conclude that no object can go faster than speed of light? Or maybe he did, I do not know. I feel I am missing some contexts here.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you might get better answers on http://hsm.stackexchange.com . Usually the way people thought about these things at the time (in this case 130 years ago!) is very hard to wrap your head around if you've had modern training.

Comment: I'd agree with the HSM SE idea, but also consider reading the rather more involved [history of the Lorentz Transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Lorentz_transformations) page on Wikipedia for a broader context.

Comment: @BenCrowell Thanks for the suggestion! I did not know about HSM SE. Should I ask the same question there or is there any possibility of moving this question? I am new here so it seems I cannot move my own question.

Comment: I flagged it for a moderator that you want to move the question to HSM

Comment: I think that at the time of Lorenz they were studying electromagnetic fields and the behavior of the fields at high velocities of charged particles, not worrying about masses.and kinematics

Comment: @annav In general I'd suggest that the original poster delete and repost the question on the other site. Migration is needed in cases where there are answers and other content that needs to be taken along with the question, but it's not necessary here.

Comment: You could possibly draw the conclusion from that formula that everything moves slower than $c$. What you cannot conclude from that formula alone is that light travels at speed $c$. Rather you might conclude that light has to travel slower than $c$ as well.

Comment: I don't think this should be migrated -- there's a serious question here about how relativity -- the *postulates* of relativity -- actually leads to the conclusion that no object can go faster than light. The explanation is not historical, I think.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir looks to me that it's more about why a person (an historical physicist) didn't do something than about the postulates of SR. Hence, it should be asked on [hsm.se] rather than here (see also [this Physics.Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/25301)).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to the History of Science and Mathematics site.

Comment: I would still suggest you ask this on the History of Science and Mathematics site, I suspect that you can get better answers there. Since people have already answered this question, you probably cannot delete it, but you can nonetheless link this question on the HSM site if you decide to post the same question there. @DavidZ Is the suggested practice acceptable?

Comment: @DvijMankad (Sorry for the delay) It's discouraged to post the exact same question to multiple SE sites. Asking a different version of it which is more targeted to the other site is fine. Note that if we conclude that the question is off topic according to the guidelines in [our meta post about history questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/25301), it can still be migrated. (Note: "belongs to HSM" is not really a reason to vote to close a question, but "off topic here" is a valid reason, and then you can also note that it may fit on HSM.)

Comment: @DavidZ Thank you. I agree with the category under which I should've cast the closing vote--but for some reason, when I tried to close it under the off-topic category, in the sub-category when I am asked to choose which another site it is more suited to, it only showed the options of mathematics and some one more site I am forgetting--but it didn't have an option for me to choose HSM.

Comment: @DvijMankad Oh, I just meant how you phrased the custom close reason you entered. It's best to say something like "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [reason which doesn't reference other sites]. It may fit on [other site]."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If I had to sum up my findings in a sound bite it would be this: Einstein was the first to derive the Lorentz transformation laws based on **physical principles**--namely that the speed of light is constant and the principle of relativity. The fact that Lorentz and Poincaré were not able to do this naturally leads to why they were not able to justify making any fundamental statements about the nature of space and time--namely that nothing can go faster than light.

---

This is seen by a careful reading of the Einstein (1905) – Special relativity section of the [History of Lorentz Transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Lorentz_transformations#Lorentz_transformations_in_pure_mathematics_before_1905) Wikipedia article

> On June 30, 1905 (published September 1905) Einstein published what is now called special relativity and gave a **new** derivation of the transformation, which was based **only** on the principle on relativity and the principle of the constancy of the speed of light. [Emphasis mine]

---

Furthermore, it is stated that (idem)

> While Lorentz considered "local time" to be a mathematical stipulation device for explaining the Michelson-Morley experiment, Einstein showed that the coordinates given by the Lorentz transformation were in fact the inertial coordinates of relatively moving frames of reference.

My reading of this seems so indicate that that at the time of publishing, Lorentz considered the notion of "local time" (via his transformations) to be just a convenient theoretical device, but didn’t seem to have a justifiable reason for why it it should be **physically** true.

---

It looks obvious in hindsight I know, but model building is tough. So the reason, in short, seems (to me) to be this: As far as Lorentz saw it, he was able to "explain" the Michaelson-Morely experiment in a way not unlike the way that Ptolemy could explain the orbits with epicycles. Did it work? *Yes*, but its **mechanism** lacked physical motivation.

That is, he didn't have a **physical** reason for such a transformation to arise. Rather it was Einstein who showed that these transformation laws could be derived from a single, **physical** assumption--the constancy of the speed of light. **This** insight was the genius of Einstein.

---

Picking up at the end of the last blockquote, we further have that (idem)

> For quantities of first order in v/c, this was also done by Poincaré in 1900; while Einstein derived the complete transformation by this method. Unlike Lorentz and Poincaré who still distinguished between real time in the aether and apparent time for moving observers, Einstein showed that the transformations concern the nature of space and time.

This implies actually that Lorentz and Poincaré **were** able to derive the Lorentz transformations to first order in $\beta$, but since they believed that the Aether existed they failed to be able to make the fundamental connection to space, time and the constancy of the speed of light.

The failure to make this connection means that there would have been no justifiable reason to take it physically serious. So, to Lorentz and Poincaré the Lorentz transformation laws would remain ad-hoc mathematical devices to explain the Michaelson-Morley experiment within the context of the Aether but not saying anything fundamental about space and time. This failure to conclude any fundamental laws about the nature of spacetime subsumes, by implication, making any statements such as no moving object can surpass the speed of light.

---

**Edit**: @VladimirKalitvianski has pointed me to [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9), which provides the opinions of historians on the matter.

> Poincaré's work in the development of special relativity is well recognised, though most historians stress that despite many similarities with Einstein's work, the two had very different research agendas and interpretations of the work.
>
> Poincaré developed a similar physical interpretation of local time and noticed the connection to signal velocity, but contrary to Einstein he continued to use the Aether in his papers and argued that clocks at rest in the Aether show the "true" time, and moving clocks show the local time. So Poincaré tried to keep the relativity principle in accordance with classical concepts, while Einstein developed a mathematically equivalent kinematics based on the new physical concepts of the relativity of space and time.

Indeed this resource is useful, as it adds an additional dimension as to why Lorentz didn't publish any claims about a maximum signal velocity. It reads rather clearly, so I won't bother summarizing it.

Comment: H. Poincaré has derived the Lorentz transformations exactly. His presentation in US, his "compte rendu" (résumé) and his full article on this subject show that he followed and mastered well the physics. His words about "coup de pouce" (experimental data) and other things were motivated by the observable physics. So A. Einstein postulated what had beed already been established from physical motivation by others.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski That's extremely interesting. What year? would you mind giving me a citation so I can update my answer? I by no means claim to be an expert on this matter, rather I'm just closely reading the wiki and related sources.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9

Comment: Poincare always believed in the ether as an absolute rest frame, an idea which Einstein abandoned in his 1905 paper.  So Einstein usually gets credit.  However, the absence of an absolute rest frame is not absolute - consider the frame in which the microwave background radiation is the same color in all directions.

Comment: Actually, Lorentz did have a physical reason, it was a dynamic effect based on the hypothesis of molecular forces. And Einstein considered relativity and the speed of light invariance to be phenomenological postulates, not "physical" principles, and was dissatisfied with them. So the real difference between them is the opposite to the one described: Lorentz and Poincare derived the transformations from hypothetical dynamics, whereas Einstein did from kinematic postulates. Moral: less Wikipedia, see [Zahar Why Did Einstein's Programme Supersede Lorentz's?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/686604).

Comment: I would actually describe the history in the complete opposite way. Lorentz was trying to _physically_ explain why the contraction occurred by invoking the dynamics of the ether, which was supposed to actually squish the objects smaller. Einstein did the opposite -- he essentially postulated it occurred with no dynamical mechanism whatsoever; just saying "space and time work like that". Nowadays we know Einstein was right, but at the time this was deeply unsatisfying to many. It looked like he was starting from a nonsensical axiom and using it to write down the answer without derivation.

Comment: In fact, I would strongly caution against _any_ description of the history of science that sounds like "everybody except for <person who made the theory we now know to be correct> was just sitting around without really trying to explain what was going on and getting it wrong". That is always the consequence of oversimplification. If it really were that simple, it would have been discovered long before Einstein, as the OP says.

Comment: This would not be the only time Einstein advanced physics by being willing to accept the natural inferences that followed from earlier work. Remember how Max Planck resisted for years his own derivation that thermal radiation was emitted in discrete packets.

Comment: I realize how unnatural it should be for Lorentz to think of posing any fundamental claims about the nature of space and time (such as a speed limit) because his theory was specifically about how objects show the "wrong" length/time exhibits while moving because of their interaction with the said Aether. But, still, he should have thought about the purely mathematical issue with his machinery that it breaks down if $v\geq c$. Is there any light on his thoughts on this? I know this question belongs to the HSM site but since it has been extensively explored here, I will leave this comment.

Comment: As can be seen in the 1st paragraph of Section 27 in his 1916 popular science book "Relativity:  The Special and General Theory" (available free online through Wikisource), Einstein did not believe in the constancy of the speed of light, at least by the time he had published GR.  I'd assume this, in combination with the fact that black holes had been hypothesized early in the 19th Century, was because of the possibility of temporal and / or spatial separations of causality, which the scale invariance of GR can accomodate.  Their utility in contemporary "bouncing" cosmologies continues.

Answer (score 12):

Because typically if you find an expression that seems to break down at some value of $v$, you would conclude that the expression simply loses its validity for that value of $v$, not that the value isn't attainable. Presumably this was the conclusion of Lorentz and others.

The reason Einstein concluded otherwise is that special relativity gives a physical argument for "superluminal speeds are equivalent to time running backwards" -- the argument is "does a superluminal ship hit the iceberg before or after its headlight does?"

This depends on the observer, and because the headlight would melt the iceberg, the consequences of each observation are noticeably different. The only possible conclusions are "superluminal ships don't exist", "time runs backwards for superluminal observers", or "iceberg-melting headlights don't exist".

Comment: [They are not cost-effective, apparently](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a219031.pdf).

Comment: @JdeBP Funny! What search term did you use to uncover that?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/130/) is where he started, but it's related, and it's what I thought of.